# Trying to prove that cardinality of power sets are equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

So if we have two sets $X$ and $Y$, we know that if $|X| = |Y|$, then $|P(X)| = |P(Y)|$.  This means that there is a bijection $f: X → Y$.

**What would a function be that maps elements of $P(X)$ to elements of $P(Y)$?**

I can try to use the existing function $f$ to prove this new function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Big HINT: There’s really only one reasonable thing to try: for $A\subseteq X$ let $F(A)=\{f(x):x\in A\}$.

Comment: What that means is that if $A$ is a subset of $X$, then $F(A)$ means that $x$ is an element of $A$?

Comment: @Victor: I don’t understand your question, I’m afraid. $F$ is the desired bijection from $\wp(X)$ to $\wp(Y)$; if $A\subseteq X$, then $F(A)\subseteq Y$.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but where do powersets come into play in your answer? Don't we need to say something of how $X ∈ |P(X)|$?

Comment: @Victor: (1) What kind of thing is a member of $\wp(X)$? (2) $X\in|X|$ doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say don't we need to also have something similar to $X ∈ |P(X)|$?

Comment: @Victor: That still doesn’t make much sense. What you need is a bijection from $\wp(X)$ to $\wp(Y)$, and I gave you one; all you have to do is prove that the $F$ that I described **is** a bijection from $\wp(X)$ to $\wp(Y)$.

Comment: I see the bijection, in order to prove it's actually a bijection, I need to prove that it's surjective and injective, correct?

Comment: @Victor: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: So I'm trying to prove it is surjective, that means that for the fuction $F:X→Y$ is surjective if for every $Z∈Y$ there is at least one $D∈X$ such that $F(X)=Y$?

Comment: @Victor: If you mean ‘such that $F(D)=Z$’, then yes. And you can use the fact that $f^{-1}$ exists to find $D$.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the best approach.  How wold I prove that the function we defined is surjective?

Comment: @Victor: I pretty much told you one easy way in my previous comment.

Comment: When you say $ f^−$, are you referring to the $f$ where $ f:X→Y?$

Comment: @Victor: Yes: it’s a bijection, so it has an inverse $f^{-1}$ that is a bijection from $Y$ to $X$. You don’t absolutely need that fact in order to show that $F$ is a bijection, but it does make life very easy. If you don’t know that fact, you can directly use the fact that $f$ is a bijection to show, for instance, that if $Z\subseteq Y$, and we let $D=\{x\in X:f(x)\in Z\}$, then $F(D)=Z$, thereby showing that $F$ is a surjection.

Comment: Awesome! Because it's a bijection, we also know its injective, but how would i prove that?

Comment: @Victor: The standard approach works: suppose that $F(A)=F(B)$, and show that necessarily $A=B$.

Comment: So because $X ∈ P(X)$, and $Y ∈ P(Y)$, and because $|S| = |Y|$, then |P(X)|=|P(Y)|$

Comment: @Victor: Now you’re wandering off the track. $|\wp(X)|=|\wp(Y)|$ because there is a bijection between $wp(X)$ and $\wp(Y)$. (I’m going to have leave now; I probably won’t be back for several hours.)