# Are there functions from $P(\Bbb Z)$ to $P(\Bbb N)$ that are bijective?

Tags: functions

I've been trying to find a function from $P(\Bbb Z)$ to $P(\Bbb N)$ that are bijective. I've found some but all of them are surjective but not injective.

Comment: Sure. Any bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ induces in a natural way a bijection between their power sets.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452246/trying-to-prove-that-cardinality-of-power-sets-are-equal

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** If $f\colon X\to Y$ is a bijection, then there is a way to "pull" it to a bijection $F\colon\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(Y)$.

What is the most natural way of using $f$ to match a subset of $X$ to a subset of $Y$?

Comment: I don't know if I'm on the wrong track, I think that those functions are of the type absolute value... But they don't work!

Comment: Don't work with a concrete $f$. Work with an abstract $f$. **THEN** try to find a concrete $f$ and compute the $F$ which it induces.

Comment: Ok so my abstract $f$ should be divided in two cases: $x \ge 0$ and $x < 0$ (that works for bijections from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb N$). So I guess my bijection $F$ should also be divided in two cases?

Comment: No. Forget all about $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$. Forget all the details. Abstracting this problem makes is insanely easier to solve. You $f\colon X\to Y$ which is a bijection. Now go. Use the second line of my hint.

Comment: Well, I guess the most natural way to match them is just $X$, which is a bijection... I'm sorry, I can't see it :S

Comment: You're dug too deep into your frustration. Take a short break, take a short walk outside, watch some TV, play some games (I have to leave anyway :-P) and when you return, refreshed, think about the ways that you know to take a function mapping *elements* and turn it into something which maps *sets of these elements*. There are two fairly obvious constructions, either one would work if you start with a bijection (although the domain and range would be reversed). It's not hard, you're just not seeing it. Seriously, take a break from this question for like an hour, and try again.